# Is there a reason to forward declare main in C++

Tags: c++

I'm going through some code from someone who has left the company and there are forward declarations of `main()` in many of the application source files. I have never seen this in C, which is my main language.

Is there a reason in C++, or C for that matter, to forward declare `main()`?

Comment: Since you are not permitted to call `main()` in `c++` I don't see a good reason.

Comment: At university our professor wants us to write the functions under the main. and then forward declare them for understanding purposes I think. It doesnt really matter what you do tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `main()` directly in C++ is not allowed so there is no real need to forward declare it. A forward declaration allows us to tell the compiler about the existence of an identifier before actually defining the identifier.

In the case of functions, this allows us to tell the compiler about the existence of a function before we define the function’s body. This way, when the compiler encounters a call to the function, it’ll understand that we’re making a function call, and can check to ensure we’re calling the function correctly, even if it doesn’t yet know how or where the function is defined.

So you don't have to worry about the forward declared main. If you want you can just clear them off.

Comment: This needs one addition: calling `main` is not allowed, which is why there's no need for a forward declaration. +1.

Comment: I'd really like that addition too. This answer, as it stands, does not say why you would, or would not, forward declare `main`, it just describes forward declarations and claims that there is no real need to forward declare `main`.

Comment: Actually, forward declaration of main is allowed, I just checked it. @evading there is no real reason to do it but it doesn't mean you can't do it.

Comment: @AlwinJoseph Yes, but since calling `main` apparantly is not allowed that is the best reason for not doing it.